# Does Qt Commercial have any modules that LGPL version doesn't

Tags: qt

I want to know whether the only difference between Qt Commercial and its LGPL version is that when you develop you app with LGPL version you have to link to Qt libraries dynamically( and some other rules) or there are some modules in Qt commercial that LGPL version doesn't have them. I searched Stackoverflow and almost all of them explain differences between Commercial and LGPL conceptually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Qt Charts](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/06/19/qt-charts-1-3-0-released-2/) is only licensed to commercial users (per [Qt Add-on Page](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Add-Ons/)).  That is the only thing I've come across that required the commercial license.

Comment: It now looks like Qt Charts is available for all licenses, no? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's changed, they're mostly the same, as confirmed [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/44066-What-are-the-differences-between-Commercial-and-Open-Source-Versions). I think you can also receive direct customer support if you pay for the commercial licence.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are the same. The license model focuses on your changes in Qt's source - if you pay Digia you can keep them closed. If you use open source model you have to publish your modifications.

Licensing & Contact: [http://qt.digia.com/licensing](http://qt.digia.com/licensing/)